# No Layer & Culling Mask

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

How can I have no layer and culling mask selected on a camera?

I don't mean selecting nothing, because there is a nothing option. I mean nothing, as seen in the attached image...

I am having difficulty with a camera rendering, and when I compare it to an already-shipped app, I can see that the only difference is that I have some irrelevant layer and culling mask selected, but that app has nothing selected, so I am trying to do the same, but even when I disable every single option, I still get the nothing option, but as you can see in the picture, there is literally nothing in the settings of that app.

[image]

Comment: probably bcause the layer was either imported and the layer is missing or it has been removed?

Comment: @BugFinder OK, I see, thank you. Could it also be that they are modified dynamically via script somewhere?

Comment: maybe, but Id put my money on something deleted or not setup before importing first

Comment: I'ld go with BugFinder: My first guess the according layer was assigned and then removed in the project's layer settings. Or as also already said: you imported/copied the camera from a different project that has different layers then your project.